# Question regarding root systems of a complex Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a semi-simple Lie algebra with Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak h$ and root system $\Phi$. I have seen it stated that for any $\alpha \in \Phi$, $-\alpha \in \Phi$, and that this is a consequence of the antisymmetry of $\mathsf {ad} : \mathfrak h \to \mathsf {End}(\mathfrak h)$ with respect to the Killing form $k$. I have been unable to prove this. I have tried to prove it by expanding

$$k(\mathsf{ad} _h(x), y) = k([h, x],y) = -k(x, [h,y]),$$

but I haven't been able to get anywhere. Do you have any hints, or the full proof?

Comment: The proof I know for this uses that for any two weight spaces $\mathfrak g_\alpha$ and $\mathfrak g_\beta$ we have $k(\mathfrak g_\alpha, \mathfrak g_\beta) =0$ unless $\alpha+\beta=0$ (which is not hard to show from the definition of the Killing form), and that the Killing form is non-degenerate which is a well-known fact (Cartan's criterion) about semisimple Lie algebras.

Comment: This is always proved for a study of semisimple Lie algebras, usually at the section "The root space decomposition". At this site, there are many references, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116743/if-alpha-is-a-root-of-a-simple-lie-algebra-then-prove-that-the-only-multiple?rq=1). The proof goes exactly as Torsten says. Later it is showed that $\Bbb Z\alpha \cap \Phi=\{\alpha,-\alpha\}$.

Comment: Okay, I have seen some proofs like that, but I didn't know if there was one that involved the antisymmetry of the killing form. I'm just getting into Lie algebras, and the lecture I watched didn't prove much of anything.